# py.test tests fail in Pycharm 2017.1 due to runner current directory

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

Just installed the new version of Pycharm 2017.1 and all of my py.test test cases stopped working. Did a little digging and it seems like previous versions of Pycharm used to run test cases from the project `Test` directory. Now Pycharm seems to run tests from the project `Root` directory--hence test discovery is not working properly.

Others have identified the same [problem](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000140784-py-test-tests-fail-in-2017-1-due-to-runner-current-directory?page=1#community_comment_115000174504), but no solutions yet.

I have tried to manually set the Working Directory in the `Edit Configurations` but that did not work. Any one have a suggestion to fix this issue?

Note, that I used to be able to right click on a test case and `Pycharm` would give me the option to run only that single case. Now that option does not appear any more. Perhaps that could be related to test discovery, as I am getting the error message `Empty test suite.`

**ADDED**

Error log for Pycharm. Note that the test is run from the package root directory instead of the `../test directory`:

```
Testing started at 6:15 PM ...
Launching py.test with arguments 
test_pyugend.py::test_bokeh_sweep_plot_overall
ERROR: file not found: test_pyugend.py::test_bokeh_sweep_plot_overall
============================= test session starts 
==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: 


/media/krishnab/jaimini/development/gender_equity/
university_gender_dynamics/py_package_ugend, inifile: 

========================= no tests ran in 0.00 seconds 
=========================

Process finished with exit code 0
Empty test suite.
```

My `Pycharm` version info is:

```
PyCharm 2017.1
Build #PY-171.3780.115, built on March 24, 2017
Licensed to shrikrishna bhogaonker
Subscription is active until January 13, 2018
For educational use only.
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b13 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.4.0-59-generic
```

The Run Configuration captured in this picture.
[image]

Comment: Can you share the error log and your pycharm run config?

Comment: @KashifSiddiqui I updated the OP as you requested.

Comment: Can you try changing the `Working directory` field? Try changing it to your project dir and lets see what happens

Comment: Have you already submitted a YouTrack issue to jetBrains? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

Comment: Hello @SvenR.Kunze yep, submitted to Jetbrains https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23361 . No response yet, but there are +3 votes.

Comment: @KashifSiddiqui I tried your suggestion for the working directory, but that did not fix the issue.

Comment: So as of right now I ended up basically rewriting my test cases to match the new testing architecture for `Pycharm.` But if anyone has a suggestion on how to fix the OP, please submit it.

Comment: I had issue with this too, but I, as usual, deleted all previous test configurations and just selected test (ctrl+shift+r on my Mac) and selected to run py.test -- it worked flawlessly afterwards.

Comment: @sashk such a pain. I ended up rewriting my test cases, but now they work in 2017.1 but they don't work in Pycharm 2016.3--because the paths for the imports are different. I did delete and recreate the Run Configurations, but the problem is the import paths. So in 2016.3 I used the import path packagename.Model but in 2017.1 I have to use the import path packagename.packagename.Model. So I can't go back and forth between two versions of Pycharm.

Comment: @krishnab that strange. It seems your project setup is differently. What do you have in the project structure? Did you setup it the same way? It sounds like it was properly in the 2016.3, but something is odd in 2017.1.

Comment: @sashk Yeah, I use a cookiecutter package template, so within the project directory Packagename, there is a source directory also named Packagename. I did not change anything in the directory structure when I upgraded Pycharm, but for some reason Pycharm started throwing import errors unless I changed my imports from Packagename.Model to Packagename.Packagename.Model--where Model.py is a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having the same situation. updated pycharm to version 2017.1.2.it works for me now.

PyCharm 2017.1.2
Build #PY-171.4249.47
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 x86_64
Mac OS X 10.11.4

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/PyCharm+171.4249.47+Release+Notes?fromIDE

Comment: Yeah, that is what I ended up doing too. But it was such a mess. I had rewritten my test cases to work with pycharm 2017.1. Then I had to rewrite them back to the old way for pycharm 2017.2. Haha. Oh well, that is behind me now.